# On the Bogoliubov-de Gennes (BdG) equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, superconductivity, many-body

I'm a graduate student majoring in mathematics, in particular nonlinear PDEs.
So I know very little about physics, including quantum mechanics.
I'm interested in the Bogoliubov-de Gennes (BdG) equation from a mathematical viewpoint.

BdG Eq. is an evolution equation of coupled operator $(\gamma(t), \alpha(t))$, see Eq. (1.11) in [1] for details.
I can understand the meaning of $\gamma(t)$ since it appears in the (reduced) Hartree-Fock equation, which I know a little about. However, I don't know the meaning of $\alpha(t)$, which is called the "two-particle coherence operator" or "diagonal and off-diagonal correlations."

I want to ask that "What is $\alpha(t)$?"
I want an *intuitive* explanation for the meaning of $\alpha(t)$.

I'm sorry for posting a similar question as one I posted to mathoverflow;
I have no answer in mathoverflow.

[1] N. Benedikter, J. Sok, J.P. Solovej: The Dirac-Frenkel principle for reduced density matrices, and the Bogoliubov-de Gennes equations | https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00023-018-0644-z

Comment: Crossposted from https://mathoverflow.net/q/428573